# how can i lowercase object value/data in javascript using underscore for HTML5 document

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, underscore.js, lowercase

I have a array of objects (`arr`), each object has 3 properties **`(Department, Categories, ProductTypes)`**, the values for these properties are a mixture of upper and lower case. I have created a duplicate array of `arr` and named it `arr2`. i needed to do a comparison between `arr` and a search filter (which is already lowercased) so it returns an array of objects back with the matching criteria and assign to `arr` using:

```
arr=_.where(arr2,filter);
```

so I’m thinking to iterate through `arr2` and lowercase everything in here, as follows:

```
_.each( arr2, function(item){ //loop around each item in arr2
    _.each( item, function(properties){ //loop around each property in item
        properties=properties.toLowerCase();
        console.log("Item: ",item,"ID: ",properties); 
    });
});
```

however i get the following output in chrome:

```
Default1.html:109 Item:  Object {Departments: "Dep1", Categories: "Cat1", ProductTypes: "Prod1"} ID:  dep1
Default1.html:109 Item:  Object {Departments: "Dep1", Categories: "Cat1", ProductTypes: "Prod1"} ID:  cat1
Default1.html:109 Item:  Object {Departments: "Dep1", Categories: "Cat1", ProductTypes: "Prod1"} ID:  prod1
```

How can I change the “`Dep1/Cat1/Prod1`” values to lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some experimenting I managed to solve this, my final code snippet:

```
var arr2 = [];

_.each( arr, function(item){ //loop around each item in arr
    _.each( item, function(properties, id){ //loop around each property in item
        if (filter[id] == (item[id].toLowerCase())) {
            arr2.push( item );
        }
    });
});
```

Basically `arr2` is declared empty initially, I iterate through `arr` via underscore for each item object, then iterate though each of the properties within the item object. I can then check if the search filter variable (which is already lowercase) equals the item's property value in lowercase, if so then add item object to `arr2` object array. Simple!

There might be a more shorter function available in underscore to tidy this up even more.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the when you use `for each` or `for in` loops, you get temp variables which are copies of the original and changes will apply only to the copy.

Here is working code:

```
arr2 = [{ObjectCategories: "Cat1", Departments: "Dep1", ProductTypes: "Prod1"}]

for (var i =0 ; i<arr2.length; i++){
    for (var key in arr2[i]){
        if (key === undefined || arr2[i][key] === undefined) {
            continue;
        }
        console.log(key)
        console.log(arr2[i][key])
        arr2[i][key] = arr2[i][key].toLowerCase();
    };
};
console.log(arr2[0])
```

For the sake of comparing the following code will **not** work:

```
arr2 = [{ObjectCategories: "Cat1", Departments: "Dep1", ProductTypes: "Prod1"}]

for (var item in arr2){
    for (var key in item){
        if (key === undefined || item[key] === undefined) {
            continue;
        }
        console.log(key)
        console.log(item[key])
        item[key] = item[key].toLowerCase();
    };
};
console.log(arr2[0])
```

You maybe find [this](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/) interesting.